# Swapping object variables in Javascript without using a 3rd variable

Tags: javascript

There is a well known method to swap 2 numeric variables without using a 3rd variable with simple arithmetic operations.

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
b += a;
a = b - a;
b -= a;
console.log(a); //5
console.log(b); //3
```

No mystery here. But I need to swap two variables that are objects and I have no idea how to tackle this.

The objects are very complex with properties of different data types and methods. Here is an example for simplification:

```
a = {
  label: "xxxxxxx",
  active: false,
  doThatThang: function(val) {
    //some code
  }
};
```

I'm currently using a 3rd variable to perform the swap but the objects are really big and it's messing with the animation where the variables are swapping values.

Comment: You have to use a third variable. The size of the objects shouldn't be relevant, because you are only swapping references.

Comment: you need third variable to swap two objects because the at the time of assigning object to variable you may get type mismatch error.

Comment: @4castle The animation is getting messed up when I perform the swap. As a soon as I remove it, it works smoothly.

Comment: It sounds like your issue is with your animation and swapping... not because of a third variable.

Comment: Why would you use the method you show on numbers? Using a third variable is easier to understand and therefore more maintainable. (And in any case with the newer version of JS you can do `[a,b] = [b,a]`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a=1,
b=2,
output=document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML="<p>Original: "+a+", "+b+"</p>";
b = [a, a = b][0];
output.innerHTML+="<p>Swapped: "+a+", "+b+"</p>";

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: What is ``b = [a, a = b][0];``? What does exactly do? and Why did it work?

Comment: It's one-liner to swap the values of two variables

Comment: While your approach solved my issue (the animation isn't "blinking" anymore) it'll be great to have the solution explained. I'm really curious.

Comment: Technically this is creating a third variable; it's just creating it and disposing of it in the same line. :)

Comment: @Krease For some reason it solved the issue. Maybe because the third variable was created on a built-in process.

Answer (score 2):

Use ES6 array destructuring.

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

[a, b] = [b, a];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

Try ES6 [**Array Destructing assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

**DEMO**

```js
let a = {
  label: "111111",
  active: false,
  doThatThang: function(val) {
    //some code
  }
};
let b = {
  label: "222222",
  active: false,
  doThatThang: function(val) {
    //some code
  }
};

console.log("Before swap");
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

[a, b] = [b, a];

console.log("After swap");
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a third variable when swapping objects. There is no simpler way to do it in ES5.

```js
var first = {property: 'value'}
var second = {more: 'stuff'}

console.log('Before')
console.log(first)
console.log(second)

var temp = first
first = second
second = temp

console.log('After')
console.log(first)
console.log(second)
```

Comment: *There is no simpler way to do it.* - `[first, second] = [second, first]` seems simpler to me. (I know it isn't supported in older browsers...)

Comment: I look forward to the days when we can assume that JavaScript implies ES6 . . .

Answer (score -4):

Let Say a = 3 and b=5.
Then

```
a = a+b (ie 8)
b= a-b (ie 8-5 = 3)
a= a-b (ie 8-3 = 5).
```

Now these are swapped without using 3rd variable.

Comment: Please, read the question. It seems you didn't pass from the title and even that can't be said for sure.

Comment: Its mandate to use third variable in object type to swap these.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same algorithm as already shown in the question (except with `a` and `b` reversed, and without the shortcut `+=` and `-=` operators)?

Comment: a and b aren't necessarily numbers, nor the same type